# Can't access MySQL server remotely

Tags: mysql, router

I've been having some troubles trying to access my MySQL database remotely. 
It works fine accessing it local or over LAN, but when trying over internet I get this error:

**Host '192.168.1.1' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server**

I've done all these:

- Disable firewalls
- Grant privileges with a local client: `GRANT ALL ON *.* TO root@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'root'`;

Then when I try to connect:

```
mysql -h190.XXX.XXX.XXX -uroot -proot
```

Note that I try to connect through the public IP (190.XXX.XXX.XXX) but the error shows the router local IP (The router is configured to forward port 3306 to the server host).

Comment: Check if `bind-address` of `my.cnf` is set to `0.0.0.0` to accept connections from remotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

plenty of possible causes:

_ first in my.cnf:

```
#skip-networking # should be disabled
bind-address = 0.0.0.0  #make sure it is not bound to localhost
```

_ then make sure there is no firewall and you don't need to open ports in /etc/hosts.allow (or whatever you are using such as amazon policy editor)

_ also your grant should have the grant option (I would use something other than root for remote access):

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'myuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'pass' WITH
GRANT OPTION;
```

_ then make sure you flush the privileges (after the grant) :

```
 flush privileges;
```

Comment: The problem was in the bind-address variable. 
Thanks a lot Youn!

Comment: Thanks Youn !  (GRANT needed)